# Retrieving text from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, text

I am sure this is a stupid question but I can't figure out how to do it.  I need to retrieve a large block of text that is stored in a database.  I know how to connect to the database and submit the sql query.  What I can't figure out how to do is have it store that text in a string so I can have it echo later on the page.

What I have so far

```
$db_name = "j_db";
$table_name = "contacts";
$connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "*****", "****") or die(mysql_error());
$db = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT meaning 
          FROM $table_name 
         WHERE card = (php variable here)";

$result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Be careful not need show id and password on your posts. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `mysql_fetch_array()`

```
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
    $meaning = $row["meaning"];
    echo $meaning;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest that, for posterity, this answer be updated to reference http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php rather than the mySQL extension

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [mysql_fetch_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) functions.  `mysql_fetch_assoc` is a popular choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $url= '' ;
    $username = '' ;
    $password = '' ;
    $dbname = '' ;

    $connection = mysql_connect('$url' , '$username', '$password');
                  mysql_select_db('$dbname' , $connection);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT textColumnName FROM tableName", $connection);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         echo $row['textColumnName'];
    }
?>
```